# Awk script which takes as input the path to a directory and displays all the files whose size are more than limit?

Tags: linux, awk

I'm fairly new to linux and awk. I want to display all files whose size are more than (eg 3Kb) and where those files are found within a directory whose path is specified by the user.

I managed to do it by "hard-coding" the path in the terminal like this :

```
ls -l /home/user/Documents | ./testScript
```

testScript contains:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
awk '
    BEGIN{
        if($5>3000){
            print $9
        }
    }
'
```

How do I do this with the user specifying a directory path?

Comment: Does it have to be awk?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for why not to take that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use find, than a combination of ls and a script

```
find PATH_TO_DIRECTORY -size +10k
```

you can make it a bash function taking a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer as I can't comment for lack of reputation points:

Not sure what you mean by "path specified by user" but assuming you can read the path in some variable then just do this in your code:

> ls -l $mypath | ./testScript

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but seeing that OP originally only wanted to replace the path with a user specified value (which seems to have been still missing in the other answer) so I posted this,

Answer (score 0):

[altagir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908202/altagir)'s `find` is a better solution, but in the cases where someone wants to use this general structure but doesn't know a way other than `ls` to do it:

```
 stat -c "%s %n" "$someDir"/* | awk -v max=$maxval '$1 > max { print $2 }'
```